# How to get a value from Symfony cache without providing callback?

Tags: php, symfony, caching

**Situation**

I am fetching data from an API which returns product related data. The data for multiple products shall be loaded in a single request for performance reasons. Additionally I want to cache the results.

The products might be loaded in various combinations. For preventing exponential growth of the cache combinations, I want to cache the results on product level.

**Intended logic**

Customer loads a product page, containing 10 products. Of those 10 product, 6 are already stored in the cache. So instead of asking the API for all 10 products, I only want to send the 4 not cached product ids.

When the response is received, a cache entry shall be added for the 4 not cached products.

**The Problem**

I am trying to use Symfony's cache contract `\Symfony\Contracts\Cache\CacheInterface`. This interface has only the following method for fetching cache entries:

```php
    /**
     * Fetches a value from the pool or computes it if not found.
     *
     * On cache misses, a callback is called that should return the missing value.
     * This callback is given a PSR-6 CacheItemInterface instance corresponding to the
     * requested key, that could be used e.g. for expiration control. It could also
     * be an ItemInterface instance when its additional features are needed.
     *
     * @param string                     $key       The key of the item to retrieve from the cache
     * @param callable|CallbackInterface $callback  Should return the computed value for the given key/item
     * @param float|null                 $beta      A float that, as it grows, controls the likeliness of triggering
     *                                              early expiration. 0 disables it, INF forces immediate expiration.
     *                                              The default (or providing null) is implementation dependent but should
     *                                              typically be 1.0, which should provide optimal stampede protection.
     *                                              See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_stampede#Probabilistic_early_expiration
     * @param array                      &$metadata The metadata of the cached item {@see ItemInterface::getMetadata()}
     *
     * @throws InvalidArgumentException When $key is not valid or when $beta is negative
     */
    public function get(string $key, callable $callback, float $beta = null, array &$metadata = null): mixed;
```

According to contract, it's not possible to fetch a cache value without providing the callable for computing the cache value.

But this is incompatible with my intended logic. For being able to figure out, which products to request from the API, I first need to get the cache entries without callback.

I could theoretically directly use classes implementing the CacheInterface (adapter), but this is a really bad solution in my opinion.

**Question**

Are there any other solutions than using the adapter directly for fetching cache entries without providing callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are probably be looking for is `Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface` which has a `getItem` method.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/cache_pools.html#looking-for-cache-items

Did not try the below code but should be something similar.

```
use Psr\Cache\CacheItemPoolInterface;

class MyClass
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly CacheItemPoolInterface $cacheItemPool
    ) {
    }
    
    public function getValue($key) {
      $item = $this->cacheItemPool->getItem($key);
      if ($item->isHit()) {
        return $item->get();
      }
      return null;
    }
}
```